# Bootstrap 3: inconsistency between chrome and firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

This is the jsfiddle for my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/TE6Px/3/

As you see, firefox puts a 5px space between the two divs, while chrome doesn't. I cannot find the root of the problem. The reason I wrap the inputs inside inline-block div's is because I'm trying to simulate what twitter typeahead plugin does to text inputs.

```
<body>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Education</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="thediv"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="School"></div><br><div class="thediv"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Major"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
      </body>
```

Comment: What is your particular question? Sometimes browsers implement webstandards inconsistent, but what do you want to do or know?

Comment: I want to know how I can make the result look the same in the two browsers. I tried to overwrite default margin, padding, etc. or take care of whitespaces in the code but none of them solved the problem.

Comment: Okay, you could try it with CSS. Find CSS code that works in Chrome, then find CSS code that works in Firefox, combine it and separate different settings with selectors like `@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)` especially for each browser.

Comment: You put a <br> tag between the fields